# Firebase - Adding a new app will invalidate google services on others

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, social-authentication

We have a firebase project with multiple Android / iOS apps.

We use firebase for social logins and push notifications.

All the apps are using the same `google_services.json` and the same Firebase project.

Now our client wants to release an additional app, so we should add a new App Android with its fingerprint.

The question is: We'll have to update all the others Android and iOS apps to continue to use the Firebase services, or we can deploy the new app with the updated `google_services.json` without other issues?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the existing `google-service.json` files, you'll see that they contain a fixed set of data. This data consists mainly of persistent project information and a list of client data.

When you add a new application, the client information for that application is appended to the existing list.

Applications are only concerned with their own package names. So when a new application is added, the existing applications are not affected. They are only concerned with their own credentials, which are stored in the `google-service.json` file.

To check this, you can perform a simple test. Select one of your existing applications, remove the client information associated with another application from the `google-service.json` file, and see if everything continues to work as expected. This will confirm that each application only requires its own specific credentials within the `google-service.json` file.

So in your case the other way around, having additional clients added, should be the same result.